# Linux not recoginizing Arduino Mega2560 Clone

Tags: arduino-mega, linux

I have an Elegoo Mega2560 R3. On my Windows machine, it recognizes fine and loads exactly like a Mega2560. I have a System76 laptop running Pop_os!. When I attach the board, I cannot connect to the port in Arduino studio (reinstalled today with newest version).

When I check, I don't see the ttyACM1 device (ACM1 specifically because of items listed below).

`lsusb before plugging in`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:9102 Acer, Inc BisonCam,NB Pro
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb after plugging in`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:9102 Acer, Inc BisonCam,NB Pro
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 2341:0010 Arduino SA Mega 2560 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmsg after plugging in`

```
[65178.203006] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[65178.353353] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0010, bcdDevice= 0.01
[65178.353359] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[65178.353363] usb 1-6: Product: Arduino Mega 2560
[65178.353366] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[65178.353369] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 7563331323335130F170
[65178.357650] cdc_acm 1-6:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
```

`ls /dev/tty*`

```
/dev/tty    /dev/tty23  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty54      /dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS26
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty24  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty55      /dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS27
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty25  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty56      /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS28
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty57      /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS29
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty58      /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS3
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty59      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS30
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty6       /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS31
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty45  /dev/tty60      /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty61      /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty62      /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty17  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty63      /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty18  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty7       /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty19  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS9
/dev/tty2   /dev/tty35  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS22
/dev/tty20  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty51  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS23
/dev/tty21  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty52  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS24
/dev/tty22  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty53  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS25
```

Comment: Have you 1) added yourself to the `dialout` group, and 2) disabled ModemManager?

Comment: Oh, man I am dumb. I did add myself to dialout but completely forgot I needed to re-login after.

Answer (score 1):

Running avrdude as root works. 
Adding permissions to ttyACM0/ttyACM1 for everybody also works. Execute

```
 sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0
 sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM1
```

and after that you should be able to compile and upload the code to the arduino
The only issue with this is that you have to run that line everytime you connect the Arduino to the USB because ttyACM0/ttyACM1 is recreated. So as pointed in the comment
if thats the case than you add dialout group to your user, log out, then log in again, you should have access to the Arduino serial.

```
 sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourUserName
```